# Windows Tool or utility to validate remote TCP / UDP ports are accessible over the network?

Tags: windows, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to find somw Windows based tools that can help me validate TCP and UDP connection on remote machines.

## My Problem (just one use case):

At work, I manage many clustered servers that I run load tests against. In order to get a rich test, I use Jmeter-Plugins which provides a Server agent that opens a TCP socket on port 4444 on a target remote machine: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMonAgent

There are many times when I setup a new load test farm, that either the network, or the server configuration, or the ServerAgent itself can have issues and thus not allowing a Load test client to access that TCP connection.

The issue I have is that I dont know what part of the system is broken.

## What I think I need:

I would like to know how I can open a TCP (not HTTP with cUrl), connection to a remote server to validate that the network allows the connection, as well as the Server firewall allows the given TCP connection to be accessed remotely.

## What I have looked:

These are some of the tools I have looked at so far:

- Nmap  http://nmap.org
- Ncat  http://sourceforge.net/projects/nmap-ncat/
- TCP/IP Builder    http://www.drk.com.ar

Zenmap 6.01 and nmap might do the job I want, but some machines where not accessible to Zenmap when I know 100% that the server was accessible via HTTP, so that was strange.

I have looked at many tools and either they:

- Dont allow remote connections
- Dont seem to want to connect to a TCP socket
- Or I dont understand the tools to accomplish the validation I stated above.

I would greatly appreciate all comment and suggestions to help with this re-occurring problem I face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mick,

Firebind.com can do what you'd like to do.  Firebind is an Internet based server that can listen on any of the 65535 UDP or TCP ports.  It uses a java based client to send traffic to and from the server from your machine.

Carl

[www.firebind.com](http://www.firebind.com)